# Install PyQT 4 in Mac OS Catalina

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, pyqt4, macos-catalina

Im trying to install pyqt4 in Mac OS Catalina. I have a python code writed in pyqt4 and i use anaconda to code. The problem is that anaconda only has PyQt 5, and when i try to install using pip, it doesn't work.

Comment: _it doesn't work._ Please share which command(s) you used, as well as the output.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `conda` instead of `pip` then you can specify the version loosely with `=`

```
conda install pyqt=4
```

You also need to make sure your python version in your conda environment is 2.7, 3.4, 3.5 or 3.6 as they're the only ones that let you install pyqt4